# Django ERROR: Reverse for 'jobs' not found. 'jobs' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I have been trying to display the list of jobs in the template and when i call archived or current jobs url .i am getting the following error only when there is some jobs available
Thanks in Advance
**Traceback**
Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:1000/customer/jobs/current/

Django Version: 3.2.6
Python Version: 3.9.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap4',
 'social_django',
 'core.apps.CoreConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'core.middleware.ProfileMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\Subash A\venvdelivo\delivo\core\templates\base.html, error at line 0
   Reverse for 'jobs' not found. 'jobs' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
   1 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   2 : <html lang="en">
   3 : <head>
   4 :     <meta charset="UTF-8">
   5 :     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   6 :     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   7 :     <title>Home</title>
   8 :     {% load bootstrap4 %}
   9 :     {% bootstrap_css %}
   10 :     {% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\venvdelivo\delivo\core\customer\views.py", line 145, in current_jobs
    return render(request,'customer/jobs.html', {
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 312, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 86, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Subash A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /customer/jobs/current/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'jobs' not found. 'jobs' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

**urls.py**

From trying out things i found that the error occurs only when there is a job

```
"""delivo URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.contrib.auth import decorators, views as auth_views
from django.urls.conf import include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from core import views
from core.customer import views as customer_views
from core.courier import views as courier_views
customer_urlpatterns=[
    path('',customer_views.home,name='home'),
    path('profile/',customer_views.profile_page,name='profile'),
    path('create_job/',customer_views.create_job,name='create_job'),
    path('jobs/current/',customer_views.current_jobs,name='current_jobs'),
    path('jobs/archived/',customer_views.archived_jobs,name='archived_jobs'),
    path('jobs/<job_id>/',customer_views.job_page,name='job'),


]
courier_urlpatterns=[
    path('',courier_views.home,name='home')
]
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('social_django.urls',namespace='social')),
    path('',views.home),
    
    path('sign-in/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="sign_in.html")),
    path('sign-out/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page="/")),
    path('sign-up/',views.sign_up),

    path('customer/',include((customer_urlpatterns,'customer'))),
    path('courier/',include((courier_urlpatterns,'courier'))),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**customer/views.py**

```
import requests
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials,auth


from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from core.customer import forms
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from django.conf import settings
from core.models import *
cred = credentials.Certificate(settings.FIREBASE_ADMIN_CREDENTIAL)
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
@login_required()
def home(request):
    return redirect(reverse('customer:profile'))
@login_required(login_url='/sign-in/?next=/customer/')
def profile_page(request):
    user_form=forms.BasicUserForm(instance=request.user)
    customer_form=forms.BasicCustomerForm(instance=request.user.customer)
    password_form=PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
    if request.method=="POST":
        if request.POST.get('action') =='update_profile':
            user_form=forms.BasicUserForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
            customer_form=forms.BasicCustomerForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.customer)
            if user_form.is_valid() and customer_form.is_valid():
                user_form.save()
                customer_form.save()
                messages.success(request,'Your profile has been updated')
                return redirect(reverse('customer:profile'))
        elif request.POST.get('action') =='update_password':
            password_form=PasswordChangeForm(request.user,request.POST)
            if password_form.is_valid():
                user=password_form.save()
                update_session_auth_hash(request,user)
                messages.success(request,'Your password has been updated')
                return redirect(reverse('customer:profile'))
        elif request.POST.get('action') =='update_phone':
            firebase_user=auth.verify_id_token(request.POST.get('id_token'))
            request.user.customer.phone_number=firebase_user['phone_number']
            request.user.customer.save()
            return redirect(reverse('customer:profile'))

    return render(request,'customer/profile.html',{
        "user_form":user_form,
        "customer_form":customer_form,
        "password_form":password_form,
    })

@login_required(login_url='/sign-in/?next=/customer/')
def create_job(request):
    current_customer=request.user.customer
    # return render(request,'customer/create_job.html')
    has_current_job=Job.objects.filter(
        customer=current_customer,
        status__in=[
            Job.PROCESSING_STATUS,
            Job.PICKING_STATUS,
            Job.DELIVERING_STATUS,
        ]
    ).exists()
    if has_current_job:
        messages.warning(request,"You currently have a processing job.")
        return redirect(reverse('customer:current_jobs'))
    creating_job=Job.objects.filter(customer=current_customer,status=Job.CREATING_STATUS).last()
    step1_form=forms.JobCreateStep1Form(instance=creating_job)
    step2_form=forms.JobCreateStep2Form(instance=creating_job)
    step3_form=forms.JobCreateStep3Form(instance=creating_job)

    if request.method=='POST':
        if request.POST.get('step')=='1':
            step1_form=forms.JobCreateStep1Form(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=creating_job)
            if step1_form.is_valid():
                creating_job=step1_form.save(commit=False)
                creating_job.customer=current_customer
                creating_job.save()
                return redirect(reverse('customer:create_job'))
        elif request.POST.get('step')=='2':
            step2_form=forms.JobCreateStep2Form(request.POST,instance=creating_job)
            if step2_form.is_valid():
                creating_job=step2_form.save()
                return redirect(reverse('customer:create_job'))
        elif request.POST.get('step')=='3':
            step3_form=forms.JobCreateStep3Form(request.POST,instance=creating_job)
            if step3_form.is_valid():
                creating_job=step3_form.save()
                try:
                    r=requests.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={}&destinations={}&key={}".format(
                        creating_job.pickup_address,
                        creating_job.delivery_address,
                        settings.GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY,
                    ))
                    print(r.json()['rows'])
                    distance=r.json()['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value']
                    print(distance)
                    duration=r.json()['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['value']
                    creating_job.distance=round(distance/1000,2)
                    creating_job.duration=int(duration/60)
                    creating_job.price=creating_job.distance*4
                    if creating_job.price<20:
                        creating_job.price=20
                    creating_job.save()
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    messages.error(request,"Unfortunately we arent able to get your order,Kindly contact our fast customer care")
                return redirect(reverse('customer:create_job'))
        elif request.POST.get('step')=='4':
            creating_job.status=Job.PROCESSING_STATUS
            creating_job.save()
            return redirect(reverse('customer:home'))

    if not creating_job:
        current_step=1
    elif creating_job.delivery_name:
        current_step=4
    elif creating_job.pickup_name:
        current_step=3
    else:
        current_step=2
    return render(request,'customer/create_job.html',{
        "job":creating_job,
        "step":current_step,
        "step1_form":step1_form,
        "step2_form":step2_form,
        "step3_form":step3_form,
        "GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY":settings.GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY


    })

@login_required(login_url='/sign-in/?next=/customer/')
def current_jobs(request):
    jobs=Job.objects.filter(
        customer=request.user.customer,
        status__in=[
            Job.PROCESSING_STATUS,
            Job.PICKING_STATUS,
            Job.DELIVERING_STATUS
        ]
    )
    return render(request,'customer/jobs.html',{
        "jobs":jobs
    })

@login_required(login_url='/sign-in/?next=/customer/')
def archived_jobs(request):
    jobs=Job.objects.filter(
        customer=request.user.customer,
        status__in=[
            Job.COMPLETED_STATUS,
            Job.CANCELED_STATUS,
        ]
    )
    return render(request,'customer/jobs.html',{
        "jobs":jobs
    })

@login_required(login_url='/sign-in/?next=/customer/')
def job_page(request,job_id):
    job=Job.objects.get(id=job_id)
    if request.method=="POST" and job.status==Job.PROCESSING_STATUS:
        job.status=Job.CANCELED_STATUS
        job.save()
        return redirect(reverse('customer:archived_jobs'))
    return render(request,'customer/job.html',{
        "job":job,
        "GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY":settings.GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY
    })
```

Comment: Okay, so where the error message says "'jobs' is not a valid view function or pattern name.", do you understand what that means? Do you think that `'jobs'` should be a valid view function or pattern name? Which of those things? What part of your code is supposed to make that happen? Or do you think it doesn't need to be? Why not? Where do you think the error occurs, based on reading the error message?

Comment: Can you show what url are you calling ?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i am actually a beginner to django... it works perfectly alright when i remove jobs in 'archived' views or 'current' views... nd i tried to render with a empty 'jobs ' it worked perfectly alright...problem is only when i get some jobs....and i dont understand what that error means

Comment: @KhushalJangid http://localhost:1000/customer/jobs/current/

Comment: @19C105-SUBASHA I think this is happening because you have a variable named "jobs" in the archived and current_jobs views' ,try renaming it to something else. like : "_jobs"

Comment: @KhushalJangid i tried renaming it ..it doesnt work

Comment: The isssue is resolved thanks ... I had a typo in my template